# How can I capitalize the first letter while using '\cref'?

Tags: latex

I use package `cleveref` to refercence a figure or table in latex.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\cref{sim_figure}
```

The result is some like `fig. 1`, `table I`.

However, my expected result is `Fig. 1` or `Table I` which is required by **IEEEtran**. How can I **capitalize the first letter**?

Comment: How can I imigrate this question to `http://tex.stackexchange.com/`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is clearly outlines in the [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf).

You can either use `\Cref`, or pass the package option `capitalise`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
See \cref{fig:myfigure} or \Cref{fig:myfigure}.
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Some figure}\label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you wish to customize the way `\Cref` prints (output `Fig.` rather than `Figure`), add

```
\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}% {<type>}{<singular>}{<plural>}
```